# Как получить отношение элемента к предыдущему в Series?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть ряд элементов:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 10, 20])
```

Как получить отношение элемента к предыдущему?

То есть, что-то такое `S(i)/S(i-1)`, и ожидаемый результат: `Out:  (None,2,5,2)`.

Comment: А пример стрки вы не могли бы добавить?

Comment: Например s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

Comment: Спасибо, разбираюсь пока)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.pct_change()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html):

пример:

исходный ряд данных (Series):

```
In [34]: s = pd.Series([10, 12, 10, 15, 20])

In [35]: s
Out[35]:
0    10
1    12
2    10
3    15
4    20
dtype: int64
```

отношение элемента к предыдущему:

```
In [36]: s.pct_change()
Out[36]:
0         NaN
1    0.200000
2   -0.166667
3    0.500000
4    0.333333
dtype: float64
```

отношение элемента к следующему:

```
In [37]: s.pct_change(-1)
Out[37]:
0   -0.166667
1    0.200000
2   -0.333333
3   -0.250000
4         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Дело в том, что предложенный вами метод фактически показывает на сколько процентов увеличился элемент, т.е (S(i)-S(i-1))/S(i-1). А мне нужно S(i)/S(i-1)

Comment: @pastor_bank, приведите в вопросе небольшие примеры входных и выходных данных

Comment: Похоже вам нужен: s.pct_change() + 1

Comment: Браво, это она, откуда вы это знаете? я интернет перерыл

Answer (score 0):

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 10, 20])

s/s.shift()
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).